# gotoDate fullcalendar not working in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar, aurelia, fullcalendar-4

on my typescript page i am accessing the fullcalendar api as follows:

```
import { Component } from "../../../common.aurelia/component";
import { Calendar ,EventInput} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import integrationPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { bindable, inject, Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class CCalendar extends Component {
    @bindable() initialView: string;    
    @bindable() events: Array<any> = [];
    
    calendarElement: HTMLDivElement;
    private calendar: Calendar;
    constructor(private element: any, aurelia: Aurelia) {
                super(aurelia);
            };
    attached() {
        this.calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarElement, {
            plugins: [integrationPlugin],
            initialView: this.initialView,          
            events: this.events,
            eventClick: (info) => this.eventClicked(info),
        });
        this.calendar.render();
    }
    
    public addEvent(eventInput: EventInput) {
        this.calendar.addEvent(eventInput);
    }

    public gotoDate(date:any) {
        this.calendar.gotoDate(date); // not working
    }
```

And then i call this above page in another ts page as such

```
export class Calendar extends Component {
    
    public calendars: CCalendar ;

async test()
{ var date=2020-12-19 // also tried var date="2020-12-19"
  this.calendars.gotoDate(date);

}
}
```

everything works above except for my gotoDate function.
I have a datepicker that i want to pass in a date to the goToDate function so that the calendar would focus on that date.

it fails and says cannot read "TypeError: Cannot read property 'gotoDate' of undefined at CCalendar.gotoDate"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed that both of your components named same. I guess that the public calendar field is still unassigned thus undefined

Comment: Sorry its not the same,let me update it,was a typo

Comment: Show the exact error message please and which line of code caused it

Comment: var date=2020-12-19 ... The date string needs to be in quote marks

Comment: i tried it with Quotes also previously and it doesnt work. it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'gotoDate' of undefined at CCalendar.gotoDate"

Comment: It means that `this.calendar` is not defined. So I would assume that when you call this function, your code has not yet executed the `attached()` function in the CCalendar  class

Comment: but when i put a break point on that line,the date gets passed in

Comment: It's nothing to do with the date. The calendar object is undefined.